# Join Single level table to a multi level table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append

I have df1 which is multi level table with expenses -it looks like this (

a               60
   EUR 10
   AUD 20
    USD 30

b                  65
    EUR 40
    GBP 10
    HKD 15

both of them are done using this script

```
t_sub=pd.concat([
        t.assign(
            **{x: '' for x in ['Client'][i:]}
        ).groupby(list(['Client'])).sum() for i in range(1,2)
    ]).sort_index()
```

and then i have Another table which is with the Money of each person - df2

a - 100
b - 200

I want to Append the second table to the first one but it has to match the level of the client total only e.g.

a                 60 100
     EUR 10 -
     AUD 20 -
     USD 30 -

b                 65 200
     EUR 40 -
     GBP 10 -
     HKD 15 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what needs to be done without an example of the data, but here is a possible solution. It is not too elegant, but hopefully it will get you started and make it possible to get what you want.

First let's create the two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Expenses': [60, 10, 20, 30, 65, 40, 10, 15]},
          index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'],
                                     ['', 'EUR', 'AUD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'HKD']],
                              labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5]],
                              names=['Person', 'Currency']))

df1

#                       Expenses 
# Person    Currency    
#      a                60
#                EUR    10
#                AUD    20
#                USD    30
#      b                65
#                EUR    40
#                GBP    10
#                HKD    15

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Money': [100, 200]}, index=pd.Index(['a', 'b'], name='Person'))

df2

#           Money
# Person    
#      a    100
#      b    200
```

Now we can merge the dataframes by their indices. Notice that I gave the same name to the `Person` indices in both dataframes. If you don't have that, you might have to provide a `name` to the index in `df2`:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This doesn't get exactly what you want because the `Money` value in `df2` is copied to all rows for the same person:

```
new_df

#                       Expenses  Money
# Person    Currency    
#      a                60        100
#                EUR    10        100
#                AUD    20        100
#                USD    30        100
#      b                65        200
#                EUR    40        200
#                GBP    10        200
#                HKD    15        200
```

So, even if hacky, you can just find the rows that shouldn't have the value (those in which there is no `Currency` value), and replace `Money` by whatever you want (I put a dash to match what you said in your question).

I do this in two steps. First, I select all the rows with no value in `Currency`:

```
 no_change = new_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('')), :]
```

And then, in the `new_df` dataframe, I select all the other rows (the ones that need to be changed), and I modify the value in `Money`:

```
new_df.loc[~new_df.index.isin(no_change.index), 'Money'] = '-'
```

This gives you what you seem to be looking for:

```
new_df

#                       Expenses  Money
# Person    Currency    
#      a                60        100
#                EUR    10        -
#                AUD    20        -
#                USD    30        -
#      b                65        200
#                EUR    40        -
#                GBP    10        -
#                HKD    15        -
```